# Using a custom annotation when adding it to map

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm having trouble accessing my custom annotation class when adding it to a mapview. I have the custom class working properly but i when i add it to the map i'm not sure how to access the custom annotation through this delegate:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

i've tried looking online and havent found anything. any help would be great.

Its called like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(shops.latitude, shops.longitude);
    AnnotationForId *shop = [[AnnotationForId alloc] initWithCoordinate:coords];
    //[[CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(shops.latitude, shops.longtitude)]];
    shop.title = shops.name;
    shop.subtitle = @"Coffee Shop";
    shop.shopId = shops.id;
    [map addAnnotation:shop];
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is Simple Example For how to Create Custom AnnotationView.**

Create custom `AnnotationView`:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface AnnotationView : MKPlacemark

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subtitle;

// you can put here any controllers that you want. (such like UIImage, UIView,...etc)

@end
```

And in `.m file`

```
#import "AnnotationView.h"

@implementation AnnotationView

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate addressDictionary:(NSDictionary *)addressDictionary
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:addressDictionary]))
    {
        self.coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

// Use Annotation Add `#import "AnnotationView.h"` in your relevant `.m file`:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pCoordinate ;
pCoordinate.latitude = LatValue;
pCoordinate.longitude = LanValue;

// Create Obj Of  AnnotationView class  

AnnotationView *annotation = [[AnnotationView alloc] initWithCoordinate:pCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] ;

    annotation.title = @"I m Here";
    annotation.subtitle = @"This is Sub Tiitle";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Comment: but how do you call that custom annotation in the delegate method? i have a custom annotation set up i just cant access it in the delegate mothod

Comment: what u want...put put this code and ..follow its suggestion then it wil works fine and alos this call from delegate method too

Comment: i've added an id to my custom annotation and i want to access it in the delegate method and when i call annotation.id it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Test the annotation to see if it's the same class as your custom class:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *mkav = nil;

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[AnnotationForId class]])
    {
        // This should be safe now.
        AnnotationForId *aid = annotation;
        // Whatever you wanted to add, including making your own view.
    }

    return mkav;
}
```