# custom callout in Mkmapview in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mkmapview

I have to display custom view on annotation click in ios, I have to display 7 images, name and detail disclosure button in custom view. On click of detail disclosure button , i have to call new view controller. How should i do it?

Comment: read this my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684080/using-a-custom-annotation-when-adding-it-to-map/15684322#15684322

Answer (score 0):

```
  -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    // Define your reuse identifier.
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

    annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    // Adding Button on annotation callout  which is your detail disclosure button//
    UIButton *rightButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,28.0f,22.0f)];
    [rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightArrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(pressDetailBtn:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangePin.png"];
    annotationView.opaque = NO;

    return annotationView;
}
-(void)pressDetailBtn:(id)sender
{

      YourVC code here
}
```