# Unable to get current location to set center of map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I'm learning to use map and my objective is to display current location on the map when the application first load, instead of showing the map of the world.  But I can't get it to focus on the location as wanted as coordinates that I've got are all 0.

Note:

1. I've set in Xcode the default location as Tokyo, Japan.
2. All codes are in viewDidLoad
3. I'm using Simulator

I've tried using 2 approaches.

Approach A) I set showsUserLocation as YES.  Then set center of the map to value from map's userLocation.  But the user location is null, latitutude and longitude are 0.000000.

Approach B) I create location manager and get latitude and longitude from it.  Also getting latitude and longitude are 0.000000.

Below is the code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
     @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *myMap;
     @property CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//Approach A)
    self.myMap.showsUserLocation = YES; //tokyo Japan, blue pin with ripple displays on Default Location that I set in XCode = Tokyo, Japan

    NSLog(@"using MapView.userLocation, user location = %@", self.myMap.userLocation.location); //output = null
    NSLog(@"using MapView.userLocation, latitude = %f", self.myMap.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude); //output = 0.000000
    NSLog(@"using MapView.userLocation, longitude = %f", self.myMap.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude); //output = 0.000000

    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = {self.myMap.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude, self.myMap.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude};
    [self.myMap setCenterCoordinate:centerCoord animated:TRUE]; //nothing happens, as latitude and longitude = 0.000000

//Approach B)
    // create the location manager
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    if (nil == self.locationManager) {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    self.locationManager.delegate = self; //add as suggested
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"using LocationManager:current location latitude = %f, longtitude = %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);

    //if getting latitude and longitude, will call "setCenterCoordinate"
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

  //add as suggested
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{    
     NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation:Latitude :  %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
     NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation:Longitude :  %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

     [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}    
   @end
```

Output:

```
xxxx using MapView.userLocation, user location = (null)
xxxx using MapView.userLocation, latitude = 0.000000
xxxx using MapView.userLocation, longitude = 0.000000
xxxx using LocationManager:current location latitude = 0.000000, longtitude = 0.000000
```

Now the Output:

```
xxx using MapView.userLocation, user location = (null)
xxx using MapView.userLocation, latitude = 0.000000
xxx using MapView.userLocation, longitude = 0.000000
xxx using LocationManager:current location latitude = 0.000000, longtitude = 0.000000
xxx didUpdateToLocation:Latitude :  35.702069
xxx didUpdateToLocation:Longitude :  139.775327
```

Comment: Try on device. and print nslog

Comment: sometimes simulator use 0.000000 0.00000 lat and log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `CoreLocation.framework` to you project and add   to `.h` file 
and also

```
locationManager.delegate = self; // may be you forget to it.
```

And also add Delegate method such like,

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{   

    NSLog(@"Latitude :  %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"Longitude :  %f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    [currentLocation stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: I did add this line now, still getting 0.000000. Also I add CLLocationManagerDelegate in declaration of .h.

Comment: @user2704095 - also add this delegate method you will able to get lat and long in this delegate method. and you can not able to get lat and long after `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` line :)

Comment: did you user/test in simulator?

Comment: @iPatel - Okie, it does work now as in my new output.  My objective is to have the map focus on the current location getting from location manager.  From your suggestion and from the output, it seems that in viewDidLoad, latitude and longitude of location manager is 0.  Then how can I make the map focus on the right location when it first appear then?

Comment: @user2704095 - you need to create custom annotation and add annotation on your lat and long that got it from `didUpdateToLocation` method, you can create custom annotation by [My Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684080/using-a-custom-annotation-when-adding-it-to-map/15684322#15684322) check it now.

Comment: Does anyone know the reason why in viewDidLoad, the coordinate of location manager and map.userLocation is 0?  Is it because it needs sometime for the data to be available and that is after the view is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
    {
        currentLocation=[userLocation coordinate];
        MKCoordinateRegion region=MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation, 100000, 100000);
        [_map setRegion:region];
    }
It also updates the location if it changes and set the current location as the visible
 region of the map.Import CoreLocation.framework
```

Comment: Yes, this code makes current location as center of the map.  Now I have both parts to make my objective works (1.getting current location 2.make the map to center at current location.

Comment: This works similar to what I originally put in the viewDidLoad  ->              CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = {self.myMap.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude, self.myMap.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude};  
    [self.myMap setCenterCoordinate:centerCoord animated:TRUE];

Comment: Thanks for both @iPatel and Wizkid1490 - your suggestions help filling in my issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can set first

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate =self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

then following method get cordinate in currentLocation

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager.delegate = nil;
    locationManager = nil;

    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;


}
```